# Is there any way to detect the collision whene a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am wondering if there is any way you can detect the collision with two objects when a key is pressed,

I am making a game and I need to know how to activate the collision detection when the two objects -which are squares- collide when a key(any key) is pressed (with javascript). this is a code i have tried(i got it from another comment in an other question),

```
var box2 = document.getElementById('block'),
    box3 = document.getElementById('block2');
box2.addEventListener('click', detectCollision) 

box3.addEventListener('click', detectCollision) 
function detectCollision(e) {
    var elem        = e.target,
        elemOffset  = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        elemDisplay = elem.style.display;

    // Temporarily hide element
    elem.style.display = 'none';

    // Check for top-most element at position
    var topElem = document.elementFromPoint(elemOffset.left, elemOffset.top);

    // Reset element's initial display value.
    elem.style.display = elemDisplay;

    // If a top-most element is another box
    if (topElem.className.match(/box/)) {
       alert(elem.id + " is touching " + topElem.id)
    } else {
        elem.id.innerHTML = elem.id + " isn't touching another box."
    };}
```

- I want the collision to be activated on keypress but every time i try  to change the event listener or the e.target to other things(like keypress) it doesn't work at all, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out! this is the answer(i found it out on my own but thank you person who tried to help)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', detectCollision) 

function detectCollision(e) {
    var elem        = document.getElementById('block'),
        elemOffset  = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        elemDisplay = elem.style.display;

    // Temporarily hide element
    elem.style.display = 'none';

    // Check for top-most element at position
    var topElem = document.elementFromPoint(elemOffset.left, elemOffset.top);

    // Reset element's initial display value.
    elem.style.display = elemDisplay;

    // If a top-most element is another box
    if (topElem.className.match(/box/)) {
      alert('collided')

    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = elem.id + " isn't touching another box."
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a Space Invaders knock off using this

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
// space and arrow keys
if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
}}, false);
```

use on entire window, certain keys cause the browser window 
to move, which you don't want when you are trying to controll a character's movement. This code turns that off

```
gameArea.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){ 
var kcode= event.keyCode;
if (kcode==38)
    { //... etc
```

this code controls character when the up arrow is pressed (keycode 38)
To my knowledge "keypress" has been depreciated, that might have been causing you problems. Also, keypress and keydown may need focus to work in/on some elements. Here is a list of keycodes https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.... Game On.

Comment: thanks...   but I was wondering how to activate a collision detection between two elements based on which key is pressed, i have already got the characters to move, was my question not clear enough? please tell me if it is because i will change it. :) (i could still use that though, cause I have been having problems with scrolling when the  up or down arrows are pressed.)